# Laravel redirect after login

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5.3

Here is the documentation

> When a user is successfully authenticated, they will be redirected to
>   the `/home` URI. You can customize the post-authentication redirect
>   location by defining a `redirectTo` property on the `LoginController`,
>   `RegisterController`, and `ResetPasswordController`:
>
> `protected $redirectTo = '/';`
>
> If the redirect path needs custom
>   generation logic you may define a `redirectTo` method instead of a
>   `redirectTo` property:
>
> `protected function redirectTo() {
>       //
>   }`

So I defined it

```
protected function redirectTo()
{
    if (\Auth::user()->isAdmin()) {
        return '/dashboard';
    } else {
        return '/home';
    }
}
```

But as you may guess, it does not work. It always redirects to `/home`.

Going through sources, I found this

```
namespace Illuminate\Foundation\Auth;

trait AuthenticatesUsers
{
    ...

    /**
     * Send the response after the user was authenticated.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    protected function sendLoginResponse(Request $request)
    {
        $request->session()->regenerate();

        $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);

        return $this->authenticated($request, $this->guard()->user())
                ?: redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
    }
    ...
}
```

And this is implementation of `$this->redirectPath()`

```
namespace Illuminate\Foundation\Auth;

trait RedirectsUsers
{
    /**
     * Get the post register / login redirect path.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function redirectPath()
    {
        return property_exists($this, 'redirectTo') ? $this->redirectTo : '/home';
    }
}
```

I can't find where it checks for `redirectTo` method.

I am using Laravel 5.3.28, BTW.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

This was fixed in 5.3.29, whereas I was on 5.3.29. Still I can't help it but think there is something wrong with documents, or this `laravel` helper they created to create Laravel projects. I did use it to generate project, and it fetched not the latest version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Override `authenticated()` function instead:

```
   protected function authenticated($request,$user)
    {
        if(\Auth::user()->isAdmin()){
            return redirect()->intended('dashboard'); 
        }

        return redirect()->intended('/home');   
    }
```

Comment: @vfsoraki it is `AuthenticateUsers` trait and over here 
        `return $this->authenticated($request, $this->guard()->user())
                ?: redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());` and what do you mean by empty function?

Comment: I meant it was implemented as an empty function, that's all. Nothing important :)

Answer (score 1):

In 5.3 you can override `sendLoginResponse()` in `LoginController` to redirect users to custom page after login:

```
return redirect('/');
```

Comment: This is pretty obvious. I meant why docs mention something that can't be achieved?

Comment: Docs of newer versions of Laravel are often just copy pasted from older versions, but framework itself is changing all the time. `redirectTo` property doesn't work for me since 5.2.

Comment: What a pity. You can't rely on official documentations!

Comment: There's nothing perfect. Laravel documentation is still great.

Comment: And about overriding `sendLoginResponse`, I don't think it is a good idea. As it does some other things too, I have to repeat them. Overriding `authenticated` seems like a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

the redirectTo function works as expected but was introduced in version 5.3.29

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/CHANGELOG-5.3.md

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help

```
    protected $redirectTo = '/account';

    protected function redirectTo()
    {
        if ( ! empty(config('locales.locale_prefix'))) {

            return $this->redirectTo = config('locales.locale_prefix') .'/account';
        }

       return $this->redirectTo;
    }
```

And also change action in form

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url(config('locales.locale_prefix'), 'login') }}">
```